# Rotated divs rendering differently in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

I'm having the following disparity in rendering for Firefox and Chrome

[image: Chrome vs Firefox]

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.arrow-container {
 padding: 35px 15px;
 width: 60px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.arrow {
 position: relative;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
}

.arrow::before,
.arrow::after {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 right: 2px;
 width: 30px;
 height: 3px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 #ffffff,
  0 0 1px 0 #ffffff,
  0 0 1px 0 #ffffff,
  0 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
}

.arrow::before {
 top: 50%;
 transform-origin: 100% 0;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.arrow::after {
 bottom: 50%;
 transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-container">
 <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

I'm wondering if there's any way to overcome this difference? For the record, removing the box-shadow does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result will be more accurate using even values for `height` (because Chrome calculates fractional values of pixels, and Firefox doesn't) and simpler `box-shadow`.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.arrow-container {
 padding: 35px 15px;
 width: 60px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.arrow {
 position: relative;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
}

.arrow::before,
.arrow::after {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 right: 2px;
 width: 30px;
 height: 4px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
}

.arrow::before {
 top: 50%;
 transform-origin: 100% 0;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.arrow::after {
 bottom: 50%;
 transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-container">
 <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh nice. Thanks.